# iPhone Dev: Tab View controller. Buttons on first view don't show actions in File's Owner

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hey all, I'm really new to iphone development and am getting really frustrated. I know ASP and Javascript and i'm trying to do this objective-c. I took a course on lynda and now i'm trying to hook up a tab view.

I placed buttons on the first view of the tab view controller. I then went into the header file and created the - (IBAction) for the 4 buttons on there and added the function in the implementation file. The problem is when i go back to Interface builder and try to connect the actions to the buttons, they don't show up. I have no actions listed in the File's owner so i can't do anything. Can anyone out there please help! thanks.

damien

Comment: Post some code please =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tab view controller app make sure that class of view is your ViewController class and also in MainWindow.xib make sure all tabs are referencing respective ViewController

Comment: I figured it out. It was an accident but i clicked on the firstView.xib file and clicked on the file owner and my actions were not there. Frustrated, i clicked again but i missed and accidently clicked on first responder... there they were! I'm confused. Why did this happen. Why was it not on the file owner and on the first responder!?!?  1 more question... right now i have 4 actions, 1 per button. how do i do 1 action and detect which button was pressed and then do a switch to take action based on the but pressed?

Comment: I guess coz ur file owner of firstView.xib is not your ViewController class where you have declared make sure fileowners class is same as where you declared your button fucntion.

Comment: For button actions, as you said you have 4 buttons and 4 action, so its straightforward to use those button for action you wanted. ex -      -(IBAction)btn1:(id)sender{ //Some Action}                                  -(IBAction)btn2:(id)sender{ // Some Action}

Comment: I was trying to avoid that. That's what I already have. I want to have 1 action for all buttons and depending on which on was clicked I would do a switch and proceed accordingly

Comment: I am not getting what switch you want to do? coz for example you can set flag variable (flag = 1 for first button) on button press according to your need and can use that flag to proceed accordingly...also if my answers are helping you thn do vote my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it backwards (IMHO). create the Actions and Outlets (don't forget to save the source), then create the items in IB (note that you have to refresh IB so that it can re-read the source.

Comment: Thanks for resonding. I did do that. The actions are created in the code. I didn't create an outlet cause i don't need it.. .just buttons that throw an alert, but it still doesn't show up in IB. I saved all files, quite x-code and IB and then restarted... still nothing. I have no idea what's going on. What do i try next? Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. It was an accident but i clicked on the firstView.xib file and clicked on the file owner and my actions were not there. Frustrated, i clicked again but i missed and accidently clicked on first responder... there they were! I'm confused. Why did this happen. Why was it not on the file owner and on the first responder!?!?  1 more question... right now i have 4 actions, 1 per button. how do i do 1 action and detect which button was pressed and then do a switch to take action based on the but pressed?

Comment: each button has an ordinal value, check that value in your IBAction and then proceed from there.